# calculate the ouptut of two operational amplifiers in a series

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

i want to calculate Vs which is the output of this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRDgPi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so i just want to equation that can help me find Vs.

please help me, because i have an exam tomorrow, and i am frustrated.
thanks in advance

Comment: There's no input voltage? Is this a trick question because the answer right now is Vs = 0?

Comment: @ KingDuken i thought so too, because weget it as a homwork but i didn't look at it until now, and i am afraid that it will be in the exam, LOL

Comment: Have you been taught about offset voltages, and bias currents?

Comment: All you have to remember for op amps is that no current flows into the inputs, and there is no voltage difference between the inputs. Everything else can be calculated from there.

Comment: @Annie Be careful! The inputs are at the same voltage **only** if there is negative feedback. This would not be the case if you used an op amp as a comparator, for example.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson True, and thank you for pointing it out. I was making a dangerous assumption that the poster was in an intro class and unlikely to see anything else on an exam.

Comment: Why do you have two ground connections that are labeled "V1" and "V2"? Are you to assume that the op amps are ideal or are they really TL081s?

Comment: They are ideal.